# Navigationview and DrawerLayout can not resolve

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

I am trying to use `DrawerLayout` object or `NavigationView` Object in code but android studio can not resolve.

This is `Build.gradle`
I am using android studio `3.1.1`

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:2.2.2'
    }
```

I will Appreciate any help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31682142/5156075

Comment: if solved with my answer feel free to mark it as a correct !

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `support-v4` library, you are imporing only `support` library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

Make sure you are importing this to use `NavigationDrawer`

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
```

Make sure you are importing this to use `DrawerLayout`

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

You Need to add this dependency to your gradle file:

`'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

u need to include

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v4:21.0.+"
compile "com.android.support:design:21.0.+"
```

use latest versions of these dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your AppCompat library and Design Support library have the same version in your Gradle.

In addition to that, if you are using androidX your design library is going to be the following

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:{Your-Version}'
```

and you need to use this call to NavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
 ...
/>
```

rather than the old Design Support library call which is

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 ...
/>
```